# TM1 Rules - different time dimensions in source and target cube

Tags: cognos-tm1

I have two cubes (source and target), but each with different time dimension.

Dimension **Date of Record** used in the source cube has following structure:

```
ALL *(this is the top element)*       
- 2013    
-- 2013 Q1    
--- 2013 01    
---- 01.01.2013 (data format is "DD.MM.YYYY")
```

Dimension **Months** (without any top element) used in the target cube is:

```
-2013    
-- 01 2013 (data format is "MM YYYY")
```

For simplicity lets assume both cubes have only one more dimension - Measures. How to write a feeder to the source cube and rule to the target cube so that the data in both cubes are the same? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that the measure is "units"... change it to what you like... also, Im naming the DoR cube as "Source", the "months" cube is named "Dest"...

In the 'Dest' cube rule file:

```
## Rule
['Units'] = N: DB('Source', SUBST(!Months, 4,4)|' '|SUBST(!Months, 1,2), 'Units');
```

In the 'Source' cube rule file:

```
## Feeder
['Units'] => DB('Dest', SUBST(!Date of Record, 6, 2)|' '|SUBST(!Date of Record, 1, 4), 'Units');
```

That said, if this number will not be updated frequently (i.e. less than once a day), I'd recommend using TurboIntegrator to map the data.